# Euler inhomogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, power-series

I don't know how to find a solution of this differential equation :

$$ u'' = \frac{MC}{C-x}u' + \frac{MC^2}{(C-x)^2}u + \frac{M}{C-x}.$$

I found a solution for $u'' = \frac{MC}{C-x}u' + \frac{MC^2}{(C-x)^2}u$ : if $\xi = C-x$ you have the new DE $u'' + \frac{MC}{\xi} \frac{du}{d \xi} - \frac{MC^2}{\xi ^2}u = 0$. If $u = \xi ^\nu$ we find this equation : $\nu(\nu - 1) + MC \nu - MC^2 = 0$, and $\nu$ is a solution of this equation iff $\xi ^\nu$ is a solution of the DE. In this case, the solution is
$$ u(x) = \left( 1 - \frac{x}{C} \right)^\nu $$

Can you help me for the inhomogeneous case ? thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

We need a particular solution so proposing $u_p = c_0(\xi)\left(\frac{\xi}{C}\right)^{\nu}$ after substitution into the complete ODE we have

$$
\xi^2c_0''+\xi(2\nu-CM) c_0'+(\nu^2-CM\nu-\nu-C^2M)c_0 = M\xi\left(\frac{\xi}{C}\right)^{-\nu}
$$

but here

$$
\nu^2-CM\nu-\nu-C^2M=0
$$

so we follow with

$$
\xi c_0''+(2\nu^*-CM) c_0' = M\left(\frac{\xi}{C}\right)^{-\nu^*}
$$

now solving for $c_0(\xi)$ we obtain $u_p(\xi)$

NOTE

A particular solution for

$$
\xi v' +a v = b\left(\frac{\xi}{C}\right)^{-\nu^*}
$$

is

$$
v(\xi) = \frac{b}{a-\nu^*}\left(\frac{\xi}{C}\right)^{-\nu^*}
$$